# Debugging Angular 2 animations

Tags: angular, debugging

I have created some animations, but they just don't work as I hoped. I would like to debug them, but I can't find a way to do that. I haven't seen any information in angular 2 docs...

Is there any tools, that I missed?

Comment: The custom animation language also has its own quirks - without easy debugging, I tend to make small mistakes in the "keyframes" without having any real way of knowing that I've done something right until it finally actually starts working..

Answer (score 4):

Chrome developer tools has a nice tool to inspect animations, I am unsure whether they are completely broken or you want to adjust the animation. But using this tool could help!

[image]

See this [article](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations) by the chrome team for more information

Comment: This isn't much helpful, it will for sure show me all the animations that happens, but not debug the angular itself... (Angular won't fire some etc.)